# File sharing between raspberry pi and windows XP laptop

Tags: windows-xp, raspberry-pi, wired-networking

If anyone knows how one would go about getting a raspberry pi and a windows XP laptop using just an Ethernet cable (no router or switcher), I would be very grateful.

Details:
8-or-so-year-old windows XP laptop, 
raspberry pi B+,
Ethernet cable, 
No router,
No switcher,
I am not trying to make a server,
I am not trying to share my laptop's WiFi, 
I don't want to download server software but will if need be, 
I am not against running a virtual machine on my laptop is it would help,

The end goal is to have supper fast file sharing so I can write and run programs on what ever computer I feel like without using a flash drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [crossover Ethernet cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable). The crossover cable allows you to not use a hub or switch to connect two computers together like your Raspberry Pi and laptop. When you buy one, I suggest you mark it with a label or a permanent marker on each tip so you know it is not like the others.

[image: straight through vs crossover]

Comment: From what I understood, from the things I could find, most computers automatically compensate when using a normal cable in this way. Is this not the case for the raspberry pi? Or did I miss understand what I read?

Comment: I believe Auto MDI-X capability has been proposed with Gigabit Ethernet. Raspberry Pi comes with 10/100Mbps Ethernet. Both devices need to support this feature if you want to utilize a straight through cable. You can try with straight through cable, but do not be surprised if it doesn't work.